# Create request object from globals in TYPO3

Tags: http, request, typo3, psr-7

In Symfony you can do :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
```

I'd like to know if there is something similar in TYPO3.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this change https://review.typo3.org/#/c/40355/

> [FEATURE] Introduce Request/Response based on PSR-7
>
> The PSR-7 standard is adapted into the TYPO3 Bootstrap with a
>   backwards-compatible layer.
>
> The PSR-7 implementation brings several new classes:  * Message (the
>   base for Requests and Responses)  * Request (for Requests made within
>   PHP)  * ServerRequest and a factory based on the current system
>   environment  * Response  * Uri (a unified API for fetching several
>   parts of an URI)
>
> At any TYPO3 request a new ServerRequest object is created inside the
>   Bootstrap and handed over to the RequestHandler which can then use
>   this object for checking certain GET and POST variables instead of
>   using GeneralUtility.
>
> The proper call (usually a Controller) creates a Response object that
>   is handed back to the RequestHandler + Bootstrap. The TYPO3 Bootstrap
>   will output anything related in the shutdown() method.
>
> An example is shown with the LoginController and currently hard-wired
>   as no proper routing/dispatching is there yet.
>
> Currently this is an internal API as the rest (Dispatch/Router and
>   Controller API) will follow once the base is in.
>
> Please note that the PSR-7 standard works with Value Objects meaning
>   that it is not possible to modify any object but instead new objects
>   will be created for Message, ServerRequest and Response if modified.
>
> The next steps are:
>   * Integrate proper Routing + Dispatching for Backend Routes to register   new BE requests
>   * Migrate all AJAX Calls to use the new API and request / response   handling
>   * Introduce a common Base Controller for all regular BE requests which   is based on Request/Response and works as a replacement for sc_base
>   * Then: proper documentation for the whole bootstrap /   dispatch + routing / controller logic
>   * Integrate symfony console app into the CLI Bootstrap as alternative   for Request/Response
>   * Refactor TSFE to use Response / Request objects properly
>   * Refactor redirects logic to use Response objects

see RequestHandler in EXT:backend/Classes/Http/ and EXT:frontend/Classes/Http for the usages in the core

Comment: Ok so will it be available in v8 or only in v9?

Comment: no also 7.6, see https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/tree/TYPO3_7-6/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Http